# Is Mapstraction still the way to go

Tags: mapstraction

I was starting to write a multi-Map JS library, but I see that Mapstraction does that exactly..

I really would like to use Maptraction but it looks a little old (The commit's on GITHUB) (Not a issue if it is still "supported"), also The tutorial page, the Maps do not show up in my browsers.

Any input is highly appreciated.
Thanks
Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what your use case is - if you don't want to be tied in to any one map provider and only need standard features then, yes.

Version 2.1 of Mapstraction is currently being prepared (on the release-2.1 branch) which brings some improvements in behavioural consistency across the providers.

Because of the nature of the library development isn't continuous and tends to be reactive to changes in the underlying providers or issues being raised. That said the community is fairly active and you can sign up to the mailing list via the site.